# Connecting Tableau end user to AWS RDS Aurora via SSH with tunneled EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm trying to connect Tableau to AWS Aurora, and I want to ask is it possible to connect via EC2 ? 
I didn't find SSH tunnel when connecting from Tableau, only username, password and ssh certificate

I've got Aurora RDS and EC2 in the same default VPC, and enabled RDS port in the security group.

Comment: See [this](http://tableaulove.com/connecting-rds-redshift-private-subnets-tableau-online/) article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a built in feature for this in Tableau. There is a [feature request](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4806) open for it.

You'll want to setup a proxy to Aurora on your EC2 instance, then connect Tableau to the proxy. See [the guide](http://tableaulove.com/connecting-rds-redshift-private-subnets-tableau-online/) that tagyoureit linked to above for how to set this up.

Comment: You helped me a lot ! Thank you !